# session will be deleted after close browser nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express-session

We used [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session). our code for session:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: config.SESSION_SECRET,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    HttpOnly: true, 
    store: new MongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
        ttl: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60, 
        autoRemove: 'native' 
    })
}));
```

we used angularjs and nodejs.
after closing browser session will be deleted! why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to also use cookie-session (https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session):

```
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session');

app.use(cookieSession({
    name: 'session',
    keys: [config.session_key, config.session_key2]
}));
```